# Entity Framework 6 DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Following a tutorial, it's said that the "DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges" is supposed to update models and such everytime you run the program. However it isn't working. I googled this and it seems there's a problem with that function but the questions where from a couple years ago, has this still not been fixed or is there something  I need to add to go along with it?

MusicContext:

```
namespace MusicECommerce.DAL
{
    public class MusicContext : DbContext
    {
        public MusicContext() : base("MusicContext")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Song> Songs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No problems here. Could be another issue. Did you make a model change to trigger it? Did you add a DbSet if needed? Are you hitting code that uses the context or doing a `Database.Initialize`? Show your context code.

Comment: @SteveGreene Yeah I added a model change, nothing happened. <databaseInitializer type="MusicECommerce.DAL.MusicInitialiser, MusicECommerce"></databaseInitializer> This is in my webconfig as aposed to Database.Initialize

Comment: So MusicInitialiser inherits from DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges? You have code that accesses your context (required to trigger model update)? You could try adding `Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>());` to the *static* constructor of your context to make sure you are hitting it.

Comment: Added the last bit, and looked around a bit for help on database initialisers, and all is working now. Thanks for the help!